# django social auth using facebook data

Tags: django, facebook, authentication

I managed to install django-social-auth, but I am missing the moment where I can actually use the data obtained from facebook in order to create the username and maybe use the profile image or the about field...

I know that in the settings for django-social-auth I can set SOCIAL_AUTH_DEFAULT_USERNAME = 'new_social_auth_user' and FACEBOOK_EXTENDED_PERMISSIONS = [...] but I don't undestrand where in my code I can plug in this data, so not to have random usernames.

Comment: Firstly, you need to try accept more answers for your questions where possible - people will be more likely to help you. Regards this question; are you saying you want to be able to manipulate the username etc. __after__ they have authorized with facebook but __before__ their username gets saved to the DB?

Comment: Exactly! I did not realize the thing about acceptance of the answers. I will definitely accept more answers, I thought I should only accept 1 answer or none. Thank you.

Comment: Well, you can only accept one answer per question and you should only do so if it's actually correct, but you can also accept your own answer if you figure out the problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`django-social-auth` implements a pipeline (this seems to be a new feature as it wasn't there when I was trying it out) that allows you to insert custom functions at certain steps in the process of authenticating. Check out [the docs here](http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pipeline.html), and an [example pipline function](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/blob/master/example/app/pipeline.py) here.

So you could write a function:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.social_auth_user',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.associate.associate_by_email',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.user.get_username',

    'app.pipeline.custom_create_user',

    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.associate_user',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.load_extra_data',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.user.update_user_details'
)
```

where your `custom_create_user` function wraps the default `create_user` and create the username according o your own needs:

```
from social_auth.backends.pipeline.user import create_user
def custom_create_user(request, *args, **kwargs):
     user = *kwargs.get('user', None)
     # Do something with username
     return create_user(request, args, kwargs)
```

Comment: this is exactly what I needed. Oddly enough I read the docs and wasn't able to figure it out from there, while it is quite simple. Can I manage to use facebook extra data from the pipeline, or should I use another Facebook django app (I wouldn't want to make things too complicated).